# DocuSign Base64 PDF Conversion issue

Tags: java, base64, docusignapi

I got a `Bad Request:400` error while sending base 64 PDF bytes to
    DocuSign SOAP API(createAndSendEnvelope). Please help me in this issue.

Below is the code for converting PDF file into base 64 bytes:

```
File fFile = new File(pDFFileName); 
byte[] bBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fFile); 
byte[] bBytesEnc = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bBytes);  
documents.setPDFBytes(bBytesEnc);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do Base64 of the byte array. I have below code without base64 and its working fine for me:

```
        File f = new File(pDFFileName); 

        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] pdfBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        fs.read(pdfBytes);
        fs.close();
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.setPDFBytes(pdfBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

`byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\File.PDF");
            // Add a document to the envelope
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            doc.Name = "TestFile.pdf";
            doc.DocumentId = "3";`

I do this like that and it's workinf for me.